# Axios post params not being sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I'm using Axios in a react app to acess an api. I'm trying to post login details to  the server however when I log the body of the request all I get is `{}`.

Heres the request:

```
handleSubmit() {
    let email    = this.state.email
    let password = this.state.password

    request.post("/login",{email: email, password: password}) //just prints {} on the backend
    .then((results)=>console.log(results))
    .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
}
```

If I remove the braces and just sent a string like `hello` as a test I get back `{ hello: '' }` so clearly its working. I've tried everything at this stage to get the user input in the field but have not been successful.

Heres the server code:

```
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.post("/login",(req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
})
```

My api is a node server on port 4000 using express.js

Comment: What does your server code look like? Do you have a JSON body parser middleware for your express server?

Comment: yes I'm using body-parser, its all worked successfully before using `<form method="post" action="localhost:4000/login">.....</form>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: The object has to be stringified as querystring. You can use [qs package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) for that purpose. See the updated code.

Since you are using `body-parser`'s `bodyParser.urlencoded` middleware, request's content-type need to be set as 'x-www-form-urlencoded'.

```
import qs from "qs";

// ...

handleFormSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const requestBody = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    }

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    }

    request.post('/login', qs.stringify(requestBody), config)
    .then(res=>console.log(res))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't resolve the issue. Still getting `{}`

Comment: Upon further inspection, the results seem to be in an odd format: `{ '{"email":"joebloggs@gmail.com","password":"secret"}': '' }` it seems like the entire users details are just one big `key` value, would you know why this is?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. You need to serialize the data. See my updated answer. Let me know if that worked :)